# MongoDB Geolocation using with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, geolocation

I try to implement a GPS tracking service for my application. I've a service to push geolocation data into mongodb which works very well. Problem is that each vehicle must send a data in each 20 seconds.

As a requirement i should show the latest 24 hours data in google maps which makes a problem to receive a huge data set. (4320 for one vehicle). Is there any best practice in mongo or google maps to receive less data and show a line as the history? (Response is "json")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your JSON looks like this:

```
{
  id: 42,
  car_id: 102,
  coordinates: [
    { lat: ..., lon: ..., timestamp: ... },
    { lat: ..., lon: ..., timestamp: ... },
    { lat: ..., lon: ..., timestamp: ... },
    ...
  ]
}
```

If you use JSON, the there are only 4 ways to reduce the size:

1. Remove unused data

   1. You could remove duplicate entries from your list. If the car stands still for an hour, you will have 180 identical entries in a row. You could only keep a single one, because the drawn line on the map won't look different.
   2. Remove the `timestamp` if you don't need it. If the array is ordered, you might not need a timestamp for sorting.
2. Shrink your data representation

   1. Each character makes a difference, if you've got 4320 entries. So you could replace for example `lat` and `lon` with `x` and `y`. That reduces the size by `4*4320 = 17280` characters.
   2. Change the representation. If you don't need the timestamp, you could simple reduce your data structure to `coordinates: [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],...]` (where `1`, `3` and `5` are the `lat` part and `2`, `4`, `6` are the `lon` part of the coordinate). This may reduce the JSON size by another 20-40%.
3. Compress the data

   1. If possible use GZIP (or any other compression algorithm). That way you can easily shrink the JSON output to 10-20% of the original size.
4. Use a more compact data format

   1. Have a look at Protocol Buffers (from Google). Spring supports it and there's also a JavaScript library.
   2. There are a few other protocols that can reduce the data size. I.e. Thrift (from Apache / Facebook), but I don't know if Spring / JavaScript supports it.

That's basically all you can do.